# How can I pass a string from a C# DLL into an unmanaged language (e.g. C++)?

Tags: c#, c++, string, unmanaged, dllexport

I've had quite a lot of luck interoperating between Fortran (don't ask! :-) and C# using Robert Giesecke's wonderful "[Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports)" library.  However, one of the things I haven't been able to achieve yet is sending a string from C# to Fortran.  The worst of it is that I get no indication of what's wrong.  My Fortran application just crashes.  I've posted this problem to the most popular Fortran forum I know ([here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1888588)), and so far it has generated a lot of discussion but I'm no closer to solving the problem.  I'm thinking now that if I can solve it in C/C++, perhaps I can take that solution over to Fortran more easily.

From all the research I've done, it would seem to me that something like the following should work:

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpDll
{
    public class Structures
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MyStruct
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
            public string Title;
            public int SourceNode;
            public int EndNode;
        }

        [DllExport("GetStruct", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static MyStruct GetStruct()
        {
            var result = new MyStruct();
            result.Title = "This is the title";
            result.SourceNode = 123;
            result.EndNode = 321;

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my C/C++ is even rustier than my Fortan.  I have no idea how to make this work on that side.  Can someone help me write an extremely simple console app in C/C++ that will call the above "GetStruct" method and get the structure including the string?

Note 1: I've tried pretty much every permutation of "UnmanagedType" as well as both "string" and "char[]" with no luck, so whereas I may not have that right in this example, please don't suggest one of those unless you can show that it works.  :-)

Note 2: The vast majority of threads I've found around this topic send strings the other way (i.e. from an unmanaged DLL to a managed application rather than from an unmanaged application to a managed DLL).  I'm not interested in those, since I have that working like a charm.  :-)

Comment: C++ code is not going to help you at all, you have to deal with what your Fortran compiler can do.  Two critical problems.  You dangle and leak the string pointer, you have to use UnmanagedType.ByValArray, but you already knew that.  And functions that return a struct are very fickle, there is no standard ABI for that.  Rewrite to void GetStruct(out MyStruct retval).  If that still doesn't work then don't hesitate to simplify, you can also expose three functions that each return one value you now try to jamb into the struct, the basic way a COM interface works.

Comment: @Hans - I was just hoping that perhaps some C++ code might generate some ideas that I hadn't tried yet.

Comment: In case you care, I've solved the problem.  See the thread I referenced in the original post for the solution I came up with.

Comment: So you started passing it as a parameter instead of a return value and it started working?  Sure.  Just post the answer and accept it to complete this Q+A.